# Why am I getting this error - 'You are calling withTheme(Component) with an undefined component.' -React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, styles, material-ui

[image]

After installing some "material-ui" packages I'm getting this error. I tried several solutions but still not fixed. Help please?

Comment: We'll need to see some code and more information to help with this e.g. what did you do beyond `npm install @material-ui/core`? What have you done to trigger this error? Did you try wrapping a component with something? Did you try to use one of the existing components? etc.

Comment: I was trying to use 'KeyboardTimePicker' component from '@material-ui/pickers' after running 'npm i @material-ui/pickers', my program did not work properly. Therefore, I decided to remove all the node modules and rerun 'npm i'.

After trying this several times I decided to replace my package.json with old one and re 'run npm i'. Now getting this error. @Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solved!**

I have deleted below import statement.

> import {DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider} from "material-ui-pickers";

This solved my issue. Maybe this will help you to solve your problem as well.

Comment: 'material-ui-pickers'
This package has been deprecated
Author message:

You can now upgrade to @material-ui/pickers. Documentation for v2 can be found at https://material-ui-pickers-v2.dmtr-kovalenko.now.sh/